# HttpClient Post with string values c#

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I am trying to post a request with following code, I have this code which fails (server complains bad request, as I have no control over server so dont know what server does.)

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();     
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                    { "x", "value" }};
var content  = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync(postUrl, content);
```

and then I have this code which works

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();     
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                    { "x", "\"value\"" }};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync(postUrl, content);
```

Only difference is my value has extra `""` around it. Can anyone please why it is happening? Or if I should have used something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "works" and "fails"? Which server are you posting to? The first posts a body of `x=value`; the second posts a body of `x=%22value%22`. What any particular server *does* with those bodies is up to that server.

Comment: This question "failed" to put the relevant information and error status codes, to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

In the one that works, you are escaping the quotes. That’s what’s enabling it work. It means that most likely the value is separated by a space. That is, it contains two words. Usually you have to do a url encode for the value or you just keep it in quotes. So when you escape the quotes with the `/“` you are sending it to the server with the quotes hence it’s working.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this sample program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Show(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "x", "value" } });
    Show(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "x", "\"value\"" } });
}

private static async void Show(Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var body = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

The output is:

`x=value
x=%22value%22`

In the first case when the server reads the body it sees `x=value`, and `value` is not a string.